# html js append and getElementByName

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why i can't getElementByName?

```
<form class="form" action="#">
                        <p class="EmptySlot" hidden>
                            <input name="characters" type="radio" id="empty" disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="empty">Пустой слот</label>
                        </p>
                    </form>
```

Then:

```
$(".form").append('\
        <p>\
            <input name="character" type="radio" id="' + notformatname + '" value="' + notformatname + '"/>\
            <label for="' + notformatname + '" id="charlabel">' + formatname + '</label>\
        </p>');
```

And it's don't work:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('character');
```

Comment: works just fine for me

Comment: did you even try to access the elements of the retrieved NodeList? also, you'll need to more specific than just _it doesn't work_.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

The method will return a collection, not a single Element. You may try...

```
$(".form")[0].append('\
        <p>\
            <input name="character" type="radio" id="' + notformatname + '" value="' + notformatname + '"/>\
            <label for="' + notformatname + '" id="charlabel">' + formatname + '</label>\
        </p>');
```

Should get the first form that belongs to the "form" class.

The second should work, but remember that "radios" will be a collection too.

Answer (score 0):

.getElementsByName might return more than one element if multiple elements have the name of 'character'.

To get the first item in the list of returned elements, try:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('character')[0];
```